# NameError: account not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple registration form using django1.11.5
I created a project called mysite using the command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite .
```

And I have created an app called account using the code:

```
python manage.py startapp account
```

In the urls.py file of the folder mysite I specified the urlto be accessed as follows:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/',include(account.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

However when I'm trying to migrate or runserver I'm getting the following error.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000273BFBDFC80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Welcome\django\mysite\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    url(r'^account/',include(account.urls)),
NameError: name 'account' is not defined
```

So can someone please help. I'm new at this

Comment: Is the `account` app listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting??

Comment: Yes it is listed in there!

Answer (score 2):

When you 'include' urls, the reference to the app containing the urls should be a string like so:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    ...
]
```

You are trying to import the actual app, but that is not necessary in this case.

Does that make sense?